# The number of samples in SUS selection method

Tags: genetic-algorithms

In stochastic Universal Sampling selection method of genetic algorithm, the number of selected samples is usually static. I wanted to know if it is possible to select  the number of these samples dynamically. For example, in the first iteration the distance between samples is 1/6 and in the next iteration this value changes to 1/7. Is it possible? If it is, what conditions or factors can determine the number of the distance between samples?